# Substract the last value of the day from the first value of the day

Tags: mysql

I have an MySQL database with the following structure:

[image: Structure overview]

The following statement will get the max value of the day

```
select a1.*
from powerUsage a1
inner join
(
  select 
    max(timestamp) as max
  from powerUsage 
  group by date(timestamp)
) a2
  on a1.timestamp = a2.max
```

However I need to substract the last value of the day from the first value of that day.
Any help is welcome.
Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the result you need by using [TIMESTAMPDIFF](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampdiff) and  [SEC_TO_TIME](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_sec-to-time) MySQL functions.

The idea is to use the *max* and *min* MySQL functions to get the last and the first timestamp values of the day and then use them as arguments for the TIMESTAMPDIFF function, telling the function to return the result in seconds:

```
TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,min(timestamp),max(timestamp))
```

We'll then use the result above as argument to the SEC_TO_TIME function to get the time difference between the last and the first timestamp values of the day in the format of hh:mm:ss

```
SEC_TO_TIME(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,min(timestamp),max(timestamp)))
```

All the above can be achieved be modifying your original query to:

```
select 
a1.*
,a2.delta_time
from
powerUsage a1
inner join
(
  select 
  max(timestamp) as max
  ,SEC_TO_TIME(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,min(timestamp),max(timestamp))) as delta_time
  from powerUsage 
  group by date(timestamp)
) a2
  on a1.timestamp = a2.max
```